# Fire function at said date if user chooses to

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I want the user to be reminded to change a title every 3 months from when the user switches on the switch that says so.

Is this possible?

I´ve been looking at NSTimer, but that pauses when the application is closed

The question that has been answered is in objectiv c.
How can I do this with swift?

Comment: The question that has been answered is in objectiv c!

Comment: The answer is just "use UILocalNotification", regardless of the language. Now search for "Swift UILocalNotification", you'll find *lot's* of sample code.